# Winter18 override sizes on compound forms

Tags: slds, bug, form, winter18

With Winter18, elements sizes in compound forms are overridden to something like slds-size--1-of-1, despite the slds-size specified.

For example, this code from the [SLDS Documentation](https://archive-2_1_4.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/forms#flavor-compound-form) used to work, but doesn't work anymore:

```
<div class="slds-form-compound"> 
  ...
  <div class="slds-form-element slds-size--1-of-3">
```

This doesn't work either:

```
<div class="slds-form-compound"> 
  ...
  <div class="slds-form-element">
    <div class="slds-size--1-of-3">
```

With Winter18 overrides on our sizes, some elements don't even appear in modals.

Is it a Salesforce bug? Does it happen to you as well? How can we solve?

Comment: Spot on! I ran into the same issue with modals this morning after winter’18 live.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem and unfortunately it's on one of customer community page so can't wait for salesforce to fix it. We simply orverride the CSS with something like: -

```
.THIS .slds-form-element.slds-size--1-of-1 {
    width: 50% !important;
}
```

Comment: Do you use slds from a static resource?

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problems on a customer visible side, what makes it really bad.

I use this as a temporary solution as our components are grouped as row-element as well:

```
.THIS .slds-form-element__row {
    width: 49%;
}
```

Would be great to get an official statement from Salesforce, if something in their CSS was changed?!